# DevExpress GridView Display FK Value

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gridview, devexpress

I am using DevExpress in my Winform project, and in my form there are a few ForeignKey columns, like country, state, city, which are 'int' datatype.

I want to display the value of these FK keys ie. (India, China, Nepal, etc..) & the data comes from tables, so it is dynamic, the DevExpress GridView is a bit different, and I am not able to find a way to do that, any suggestions??

A bit detailed answer will be more useful ;)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the approach demonstrated in [this thread](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ14508.aspx).

P.S. In the future, I suggest you use the [Devexpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE even during the evaluation period (30 days).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you connect to your databese.I suggest Linq Query for getting data from database. Because,it is both easy and understandable. Firstly, you make join all table what you want to show.

```
var query = from something1 in yourfirsttable
            join something2 in yoursecondtable
            on something1.ForeignKey equals something2.ForeignKey  // join two tables each other here.
            select new {
                           something1.name,
                           something1.surname,         // you write which columns you want on the tables
                           something2.city_name, 
                           something2.country_name,
                       };
       gridControl.Datasource = sorgu ;
```

it'is done. I hope it is helpful for you